# How to write expression to display ONLY business days within 5 day frame

Tags: sql-server, vba, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am working on a report in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder and I am trying to write an expression that will display only the next 5 business days from today (i.e. a table has 5 columns and it starts from today and proceeds for the next five business days). If the day is a Saturday or Sunday, which using my [enumeration value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) would return a 6 or a 7 using the `Weekday` function, you would skip ahead to the next business day. Currently I have this expression for the first column after the column with today's date

```
IIf(Weekday(DateAdd("d",1,Today()),2)=6,DateAdd("d",3,Today()),
(IIf(Weekday(DateAdd("d",1,Today()),2)=7,DateAdd("d",2,Today()),
DateAdd("d",1,Today()))))
```

and it doesn't work. I believe this is because if we have a day like Wednesday, Thursday, or Friday, not enough days are being skipped over for the weekend days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume that you are going to start from a business day then there is a simple formula we can use:

```
=IIF(6 - WeekDay(Today()) - X < 0, DateAdd("d", X + 2, Today()), DateAdd("d", X, Today()))
```

where `X` is the number of days that column is from the start date.

Unfortunately, it breaks down if the start date is a Saturday or Sunday but if you only need it for business days then you are good to go.

Comment: This works, thank you! However, there is a change in the project now--I have to design a **matrix** which would just show the current business days of the week (not the next five business days, just M/T/W/Th/F of the current week) then find get a count of each time those dates appear for a row entry. Any advice on this? I know I will have to use a filters but I am unsure how to do that especially using a matrix.

Comment: If this works for you then you should accept the answer (and vote up of course :) ) and create a new question for your next challenge so we can take a look at that as a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use previous column value instead of using Today()
So inthe first column it will be the current date. (Apply the same formula if it can start from weekend days).
I think switch case is more easy in this condition.

Formula for current day column

```
=switch (
Weekday(today) = 6, dateadd("d", 2, today),
Weekday(today) = 7, dateadd("d", 1, today),
Weekday(today) < 6, today
)
```

In the second column instead of today() use "Fields!previous_column_name.Value".

```
=switch (
Weekday(dateadd("d", 1, Fields!previous_column_name.Value)) = 6, dateadd("d", 3, Fields!previous_column_name.Value),
Weekday(dateadd("d", 1, Fields!previous_column_name.Value)) = 7, dateadd("d", 2, Fields!previous_column_name.Value),
Weekday(dateadd("d", 1, Fields!previous_column_name.Value)) < 6, dateadd("d", 1, Fields!previous_column_name.Value)
)
```

In third column use the second column as previous_column.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, this solution also works! However, as I noted below, the project has now changed and I hope you can still impart some advice. I have to design a matrix which would just show the current business days of the week (not the next five business days, just M/T/W/Th/F of the current week) then find get a count of each time those dates appear for a row entry. Any advice on this? I know I will have to use a filters but I am unsure how to do that especially using a matrix.